# You have an error in your SQL syntax, but cant seem to trace error

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, syntax-error

I am using the following script to enter data into my database from a form. I have echo'd each of the values declared at the beginning and they are all coming across just fine.

```
    include("connectmysqli.php"); 
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://towerroadacademy.co.uk/templates/rt_reflex_j16/css/template.css">';
    if (isset($_GET['questionnaireID'])) {$questionnaireID = $_GET['questionnaireID'];}else {$questionnaireID = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['newquestionnumber'])) {$questionnumber = $_POST['newquestionnumber'];}
    if (isset($_POST['questionID'])) {$questionID = $_POST['questionID'];}else {$questionID = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['question'])) {$question = $_POST['question'];}else {$question = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['lowerlabel'])) {$lowerlabel = $_POST['lowerlabel'];}else {$lowerlabel = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['middlelabel'])) {$middlelabel = $_POST['middlelabel'];}else {$middlelabel = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['upperlabel'])) {$upperlabel = $_POST['upperlabel'];}else {$upperlabel = '';}

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `QuestionnaireQuestions` (`questionnaireID`, `questionnumber`, `questionID`, `question`, `lowerlabel`, `middlelabel`, `upperlabel`) VALUES ($questionnaireID', '$questionnumber', '$questionID', '$question', '$lowerlabel', '$middlelabel', '$upperlabel') WHERE questionnaireID='$questionnaireID';");
    if (!$stmt) trigger_error($db->error);
    $stmt->execute();
```

I keep getting the following error though and cant seem to trace what is causing it.

```
Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near '', '3', '1947679104', 'questonofngdfngodfngo',     'lower', 'midddle', 'upper') WHER' at line 1 in     /home2/towerroa/public_html/questionnaires/addanotherquestionsubmit.php on line 16 Fatal error: Call     to a member function execute() on a non-object in     /home2/towerroa/public_html/questionnaires/addanotherquestionsubmit.php on line 17
```

The table QuestionnaireQuestions looks like this :

```
    id  questionnaireID questionnumber  questionID  question    lowerlabel  middlelabel upperlabel
```

Comment: 1. Read about SQL-Injection. 
2. Print your query out and look at your db, it looks like one of the columns does not accept an empty string!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a quote on `$questionnaireID`:

```
INSERT INTO `QuestionnaireQuestions` (`questionnaireID`, `questionnumber`, `questionID`, `question`, `lowerlabel`, `middlelabel`, `upperlabel`) VALUES ('$questionnaireID', '$questionnumber', '$questionID', '$question', '$lowerlabel', '$middlelabel', '$upperlabel')
```

Also remove the `WHERE` clause.

`UPDATE` statements can use the `WHERE` statement to update existing database records based upon a condition. Granted `INSERT SELECT` statements can contain a `WHERE`, `INSERT` statements by themselves do not.

Comment: Thanks !, having a late one last night didnt help ! argh. Its all working now.

Comment: you need to remove ';' also from your query.See my ans

Comment: @Gautam3164 - my answer doesn't include a rogue `;`

Comment: @Gautam3164 - yes probably a random, happens all the time unfortunately.

Comment: `INSERT...SELECT` *can* use `WHERE`. Granted, the `WHERE` would be part of the `SELECT` subquery, not the `INSERT` proper, but it may still be a good idea to change *`INSERT` statements do not* to *`INSERT...VALUES` statements do not*, to avoid any ambiguity and misunderstanding.

Comment: @DarrenDavies I am not downvoter but I guess you've been down-voted because you've not mentioned sql-injection risk in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT` will not work with the `WHERE` condition,if only you want to `UPDATE` the row then you can use `WHERE` condition and replace this

```
VALUES ($questionnaireID',......
```

with

```
VALUES ('$questionnaireID',
```

You have missed a **single quote** and **remove** ';' from the end also.Now the query will be

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `QuestionnaireQuestions` (`questionnaireID`,
                      `questionnumber`, `questionID`, `question`, `lowerlabel`,
                      `middlelabel`, `upperlabel`) VALUES ('$questionnaireID',
                      '$questionnumber', '$questionID', '$question', '$lowerlabel',
                      '$middlelabel', '$upperlabel')");
```

But I must appreciate that you are using PDO statements instead of mysql_* deprecated functions

Answer (score 1):

```
($questionnaireID'
```

should be

```
('$questionnaireID'
```

but you should really try working with prepared statements